# Solving a differential equation with an unknown relation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Say we have an unknown function $x(y)$. But we do know that $f(x) + g(y) = {{dx} \over {dy}}$, where $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ are known.

Is it possible to find $x(y)$ like this? If not, what can we know about it? You can't simply bring the $dy$ over an integrate, since the dependence of $x$ on $y$ is unknown.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is linear, then yes, it is possible to find this $x(y)$ (with the [integrating factor method](http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mathcentre-ode.pdf) ). If not, then the differential equation is non-linear, and is much harder to solve, and there isn't a specific method that will always work.

Answer (score 0):

For general $f$ and $g$ your question is almost as general as solving the following general ODE:
$$
x'(t)=\Phi(t,x).
$$
Of course, apriori this has no explicit solution due to the (potential) nonlinear behavior of the equation, and the questions that you can answer are strongly dependent on the functions $f(x)$ and $g(y)$. For instance, if you don't have the explicit form of $f$ and $g$ but you know their regularities, you can still easily check existence and uniqueness of your equation using the usual theorems (Cauchy-Lipschitz-Picard, provided some initial conditions and a domain of course). On the other hand, if you have the explicit form of $f$ and $g$ you may be able to get explicit solutions of the equations (here the methods to obtain the solutions are strongly dependent on the form of $f$ and $g$). However, for nonlinear $f$ it is likely that the equation does not have explicit solutions. Nevertheless, you can always obtain qualitative behaviors of the solutions by analyzing its linearization around critical points of $\Phi$ and/or analyzing the existence of Lyapunov functionals, etc. As I said before, this strongly depends on your functions $f$ and $g$.